# what is QCD Background?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

I am looking at some papers in particle physics and came across 2 terms called QCD Background and ABCD method (control region and signal region). When I searched them on Google, could not get much information about them. Could someone either of those terms in a simple way for a non-physicist?

Answer (score 5):

In simple terms [QCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics) as a "background" usually refers to LHC research where [hadronic jets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_%28particle_physics%29) create a lot of particles that clutter up the results you're trying to see.  I think it has become a slang term and the use is discouraged.

ABCD method is a tool used to separate the particles of interest (signal) from the "other stuff" (background) made by the jets.  It is a set of boundaries that relies on the fact that you have two independent distributions to distinguish between signal and background. See section 5.3 here http://dare.uva.nl/document/221955

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. So, can I say that everything other than what I am looking for in the final state is a background?

Comment: The term "background" is not discouraged, at least not that I've ever heard. Its use is ubiquitous in the particle physics community.

Comment: @DavidZ I meant the mix of terms "QCD Background" where QCD is a theory and background don't really go together.  I think the CMS doesn't like it used in publications.

Comment: @DamianDulkawie Yes, "background is a blanket term that covers the non-signal". We used to say "this year's signal next year's background" :).  30 years ago QCD was the  sought for signal and the parton model provided the background.

Comment: @user6972 well, that may be something CMS does, but in particle physics in general, "QCD backgrounds" is still a reasonably common phrase.